# sum total price in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I write a code that get data from datavba :

```
        $carts = DB::table('carts')
            ->select('carts.*',
            'products.shid as product_shid', 'products.name as product_name', 'products.image as product_image', 'products.unit as product_unit' , 'products.guarantee as product_guarantee' , 'products.price as product_price' ,
            'cart_lists.quantity as cart_list_quantity',
            'markets.name as market_name'
            )
            ->join('cart_lists', 'carts.id', '=', 'cart_lists.cid')
            ->join('products', 'cart_lists.pid', '=', 'products.id')
            ->join('markets', 'products.shid', '=', 'markets.id')
            ->where('carts.status','1')
            ->orderBy('cart_lists.id','DESC')
            ->get();


        foreach($carts as $cart){
            $cart->total = $cart->product_price * $cart->cart_list_quantity;
            $cart->total_sum = $cart->sum('total');
        }
```

i want get sum of all products in cart with $cart->total_sum
but i get this error : Call to undefined method stdClass::sum()

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: $cart represents 1 single row,
You can't apply sum total for one row, instead you apply it for a bunch of rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total is for all carts (cart1 + cart1 + ... + cartn), right ?

Why don't use

```
$cart->total_sum = $carts->sum('total');
```